# on a has_many :through association, replacing conditions with lambda

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I have this association:

```
has_many :foo_participators, through: :foos, source: :user, conditions: "foos.state = 'completed'"
```

Rails tells me:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: The following options in your Bar.has_many
>   :foo_participators declaration are deprecated: :conditions. Please use a scope
>   block instead. For example, the following:
>
> ```
> has_many :spam_comments, conditions: { spam: true }, class_name: 'Comment'
> ```
>
> should be rewritten as the following:
>
> ```
> has_many :spam_comments, -> { where spam: true }, class_name: 'Comment'
> ```

Is this possible with my association?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured this out right after I asked the question. For some reason I hadn't tried putting the lambda first -- doing so works perfectly.

```
has_many :foo_participators, ->{where "foos.state = 'completed'"}, through: :foos, source: :user
```

Comment: thanks so much for this answer @johnbachir. Just tested it in rails 5, still working